# IE8 Content Issues

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, web, internet-explorer-8

Hello I have a site at http://www.jn-design.co.uk/WirralPT

It appears okay in all other browsers except from IE8 , I havent even attempted below 8 yet.

The home page list and footer is not as it should be, please view in chrome or more recent browser to see what it should look like.

I have validated all my code for HTML and CSS and it is fully valid.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: BTW: Not fully valid: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.jn-design.co.uk%2FWirralPT&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: haha that is the CSS validation link! Will correct now , but the rest is!

Comment: You should inlcude an as-small-as-possible example of the problem you're experiencing; that way when you fix your site (or change the link) this question can still be of use to future visitors. Also include details on what you expected and how the current rendering doesn't live up to that.

Comment: Understood , sorry for vagueness , In particular it is the list stylings and footer and header stylings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nav` and `footer` html5 elements are not supported by interenet explorer 8 and lower. Try to add them with javascript using [html5shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/)

Comment: I have had this problem before , my apologies! I thought I had already included this...